# Applying CSS Elements to PHP Dynamic Data

Tags: php, css

I am new to Applying Typographic and Page Layout Elements to Dynamic Data.

I have used this code - `<p><?php echo preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', '</p><p>', $row_rs_AZ_Products_Detail_pg['ItemLongDesc']); ?></p>`

to insert the paragraphs generated below from my database. The paragraphs are separated perfectly but I need to create a list formate of the INFORMATION NEEDED bullet or numbered in the middle of the paragraphs. I was instructed to place this code -

```
p {
    margin: 0 0 0.25em 0;
}
```

into the page but I am not sure how to do this. Can anyone help me with this or  suggest something better? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Data output:

```
Make someone special feel special with a Customized and Personalized full color Autograph Photo Football Sports Ball. Before clicking the Add to Cart button to place your order, please cut and past the INFORMATION NEEDED below into your email and email to tony@awardzone.net.

INFORMATION NEEDED:

TEXT ABOVE PHOTO - 1 Line Recommended [Type your text here]

CENTER PHOTO OR LOGO - (attach jpeg format image)

TEXT BELOW PHOTO - 1 Line Recommended [Type your text here]

TEAM COLORS - [Type your colors here]

YOUR CONTACT PHONE - [Type your text here]

YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS - [ [Type your text here]

(Optional) MASCOT NAME - [Type your text here]

And/or MASCOT LOGO (attach jpeg format image)

YOUR IN HAND DATE? - [Type your date here]

IMPORTANT - Your final layout proof will be approved by YOU before imprinting and shipment. *All personal information will remain confidential and will not be sold.

QUESTIONS? Email tony@awardzone.net or call Tony at 973-347-6819
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how fixed your data is, but with what you have shown, I would:

- explode the input on multiple line-breaks (using preg_split) to get an array with all lines
- remove the first two entries from the array to be used as leading paragraphs and echo them out
- remove the last two entries from the array to be used as ending paragraphs
- start a list (`<ul>` or `<ol>`)
- echo the remaining array out as list items
- close the list
- echo out the two ending paragraps